# Vue 3 Dom not updating during function call

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar

I have a simple function that is flipping some variables. (placeholder for the real logic). the issue is that Vue is not updating the dom when a variable is updated until the end of the function. I have tried `nextTrick()` with no success.

part of the template:

```html
<div>
  <q-icon v-if="status === 'DONE'" name="mdi-check-circle" color="green" size="2em"/>
  <q-icon v-if="status === 'PENDING'" name="mdi-checkbox-blank-circle-outline" color="orange-8" size="2em"/>  
  <q-icon v-if="status === 'FAILED'" name="mdi-alert-circle" color="red-8" class="q-pr-sm" size="2em"/> 
  <q-spinner-pie  v-if="status === 'PROCESSING'" color="primary" size="2em" class="q-pr-sm" /> 
  <span class="text-italic text-caption" >( {{ curTotal }} / {{ itemTotal }} )</span>

</div>
```

My very simple function:

```js
        processImages(){  
            this.status = 'PROCESSING'
            for ( let i = 0; i < this.itemTotal; i++){
                this.sleep(1000)
                this.curTotal += 1
            }
        }
```

**Edit**

I changed my function to call my api endpoint instead of the `sleep()` function.

```js
        async processImages(){  
            this.rows[0].status = 'PROCESSING'
            for ( let i = 0; i < this.itemTotal; i++){
                const { data } = await $fetch('/api/scrape', {
                    method: 'GET',
                })
                this.rows[0].curTotal += 1
            }
            this.rows[0].created = true
        }
```

The sleep function i was using was:

```js
        sleep(miliseconds) {
            var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

            while (currentTime + miliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {
            }
        }
```

It was the sleep function that was blocking the ui update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to work just fine, maybe provide some more code like your `sleep` method:

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      curTotal: 1,
      itemTotal: 20,
      status: "FAILED"
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async sleep(ms) { return new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, ms)) },
    async processImages() {  
        this.status = 'PROCESSING'
          // do what ever
          for ( let i = 0; i < this.itemTotal/2; i++){
              await this.sleep(1000)
          this.curTotal += 1
      }
      this.status = 'DONE'
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

An alternative would be to switch to a composition api and using a `ref` for the `status`,`itemTotal` and `curTotal`

[vue-ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#accessing-the-refs)

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const status = ref('FAILED')
const curTotal = ref(0)
const itemTotal = ref(20)
const sleep = ms => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, ms));
async function processImages() {  
  status.value = 'PROCESSING'
  // do what ever
  for ( let i = 0; i < itemTotal.value; i++){
     await sleep(1000)
     curTotal.value += 1
  }
  status.value = 'DONE'
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <span v-if="status === 'FAILED'">FAILED</span>
    <span v-if="status === 'PROCESSING'">PROCESSING</span>
    <span v-if="status === 'DONE'">DONE</span>
    <button @click=processImages>
     Trigger
    </button>
    <span class="text-italic text-caption" >( {{ curTotal }} / {{ itemTotal }} )</span>

  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: thank you. I did try using `ref()` still having the same issue with the UI not updating. based on your asking for the wait function i swapped it out for an API call and bam it started working. The wait function was blocking the ui update.